# Can a general homogeneous system of ODEs be solved in this way?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Can any system of ODEs in the form:

$$
\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A(t) \vec{x}
$$

be solved in the following way?

$$
\vec{x} = \vec{C}e^{\int_{t_0} ^{t} A(\tau) d\tau}
$$

($\vec{x}$ and $\vec{C}$ are n dimensional vectors, and A is an n$\times$n dimensional matrix, and $\vec{C}$ is a constant vector). I have made some research about it and haven't found any counterexample, but for example in this website: https://math24.net/linear-systems-differential-equations-variable-coefficients.html, it says that this result is only valid for a matrix A(t) such that:

$$
A(t) \cdot \int_{t_0} ^{t} A(\tau) d\tau = \int_{t_0} ^{t} A(\tau) d\tau \cdot A(t)
$$

Why is that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To see why the condition on $A$ is necessary, substitute and check if the candidate solution satisfies the equation

Comment: You need some commutativity assumption I would guess. Just as you need $A,B$ to commute to get $e^{A+B} = e^A e^B$.